# CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE is not defined in OpenCv4 on windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am using OpenCv4 on windows , tried to run C++ code in visual Studio 2017, but it says that CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE  and  CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT is not defined , some solutions suggested to use cv2 prefix but cv2 is not defined too , i am using Opencv4 and setup the path.

```
cv::Mat grayscale;
 cv::cvtColor(frame, grayscale, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY); // convert image to grayscale
 cv::equalizeHist(grayscale, grayscale); // enhance image contrast 
 std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
 faceCascade.detectMultiScale(grayscale, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(150, 150));
 if (faces.size() == 0) return; // none face was detected
```

---

More Details

I'm trying to implement Mouse eyeball tracking for mouse control using code from this repo.
https://abnerrjo.github.io/blog/2017/01/28/eyeball-tracking-for-mouse-control-in-opencv/

Currently it shows some variable as sytax error so i cant build

in this function defination **CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE** is says undefined

also  **CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT** was same but i changed it to **cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY** and it works now

[image]

Additional modules added in project
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's now called CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE or cv::CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE if you aren't `using` the cv namespace. I think that change was with OCV 3.